# asp.net jquery datepicker control with image?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

I am looking for Jquery datepicker control like ajax calendar control with image button next to text box in asp.net.

If any examples available please share with me.

I saw this http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/891888.aspx, but I donot custom control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jqueryui.com](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#icon-trigger) Datepicker!

**EDIT:**

Also, have a look at this [address](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/category/goodies/date-time/). There are more than 25 references of several datepicker ajax calendars and schedulers.